# Why is this PHP send file corrupting the data?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a project which simple stores a file on a server. When someone wants to download the file, I have to pass the request through an intermediate controller (Zend framework) to provide some protection to the file.

When someone requests the file, the file is downloaded to the client browser, howver, in all my tests the file always comes back corrupted (although it is the right size to the byte). Can someone tell me what Im doing wrong here?

```
 public function downloadAction() {
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    $files = new Application_Model_DbTable_Files();

    $file = $files->getFileForDownload($this->_getParam('id'), Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->id);

    $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');

    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();


    if (file_exists($config['mindful']['path'] . $file)) {
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream');
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename=' . basename($file), false);
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(readfile($config['mindful']['path'] . $file));
    }
}
```

As you can see I have tried it both with the Zend methods, as well as with standard PHP. Both of these give me the same outcome.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Rick

Comment: Hmmm maybe it's character encoding problem?

Comment: How are you determining that the file is corrupt? What kind of files are they?

Comment: corrupted how? have you do done a byte-wise comparison of the two files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that can cause problems with file downloads on many frameworks is a lost \n, these happen usually after the ?> of PHP, and end up sending unexpected \n with your data. These \n are completely harmless when you are sending HTML, but will corrupt any other files.

PHP scripts dont require you to close the PHP tag, and it is allways good practice to not close it. Exceptions are when you are using PHP templates (in views), where you obviously have to close them.

- Delete the ?> tag of all models and components used by the controller you are accessing (including the controller)
- Make sure you have no enters before the <?php tags in the same files
- Make sure you disabled the layout and view rendering for this action (seems to be correctly done)

Comment: Nailed it! It was some white space before my <?php tag in one class that was doing it. Took that out, file started coming through fine!

Answer (score 1):

`readfile` does not return the file contents, it outputs them immediately. The return value is the number of bytes, so this is currently being appended to your response body. This is probably what is causing the corruption.

You can either continue to use `readfile` by sending the headers first and just calling it directly:

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream');
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename=' . basename($file), false);
$this->getResponse()->sendHeaders();

readfile($config['mindful']['path'] . $file);
```

or if the files are very small, you could stick with your current approach and use `file_get_contents` instead:

```
$this->getResponse()->setBody(file_get_contents($config['mindful']['path'] . $file));
```

Note that neither of these approaches provide any caching whatsoever (e.g. handling if modified since headers).

You could also consider using X-Sendfile, which is more memory friendly and will handle the caching headers for you.

Comment: The file_get_contents is definitely the way to go. It wasnt the solution, but did overcome the sending limit problem I was having.